# How to handle custom protocols in linux using Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I'm using `setAsDefaultProtocolClient` to declare the protocol, then catching it using `app.on('open-url', function... )` . But it seems, it isn't triggering `app.on('open-url')` event.
Am I doing anything wrong in this?